# Can't install Powerline using Vundle in Vim editor

Tags: linux, vim, vundle

I want to install Powerline statusline in Vim. I found a bunch of methodes from the official documentation. I decided to go with with Vundle plugin manager, everything went good and after I launched Vim, I got this message:

> You need vim compiled with Python 2.6, 2.7 or 3.2 and later support
>   for Powerline to work

despite Python 2.7 is installed. what is the problem?

PS:

- I already installed bunch of plugins using Vundle successfully.
- I've installed Powerline package from debian repository to use is for tmux and it woked correctly.

My setup:
Debian Jessie 8.2.
Vim 7.4.
Python 2.7.9.

Edit: the output of

> vim --version

```
 VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 31 2015 23:56:29)
Included patches: 1-488, 576
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
```

Comment: Just because Python is installed doesn't mean that your vim build was built against it.  Run `vim --version` and post the output.  The key here will be seeing something like "+python" or "+python/dyn".  A "+" means your vim build has python support.  A "-" means it does not.

Comment: Please show the output of `:h` (from within vim). You probably don't have the +python line. So you might want to install a different debian package. One from vim-nox vim-gnome, vim-gtk should do

Comment: @RandyMorris Hi that's correct Python features is not included, how to fix this?.

Comment: You'll either have to find a vim build from your distribution that has python support compiled in or you'll have to compile vim yourself.  Most distributions have at least one vim package with python support enabled but I'm not sure about Debian.